# Angular/Nativescript: Listview doesn't show at all

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am busy with a very basic Angular2/Nativescript app where i'm trying to replicate a table from a web app where I display stock transactions using Nativescript's GridLayout and ListView...  i'm not sure there's a way to add all content in the ListView and not have the table headers repeat with in every item in the ListView so i've created two GridLayouts, one at the top and one contained in the ListView...  When I click on the show stock transactions button the ListView doesn't show at all.  The GridLayout with the headers shows up though...  I must be doing something wrong with the listview...  Any idea where i'm going wrong/How to fix this?  Also is there a way to debug these template errors using Nativescript?  It makes it really hard if there's no way to check what's going on...

Update: I updated my code after having a look at the link @Nick Ilive posted and managed to get it working for about 5 minutes...  When I re-compiled it just showed the headers twice but no other content...

```
    my code:

    Part of my xml template:

        <Button class="btn btn-primary m-x-0" text="Show Stock Transactions" (tap)="showStockTransactions()"></Button>


    <StackLayout *ngIf="stockTransactions.length > 0">

        <ListView [items]="stockTransactions" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector" class="list-group" color="green">
            <template nsTemplateKey="header" let-header="item">
            <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="*, *, *, *">
            <Label row="0" col="0" class="list-group-item bg-primary" text="Date"></Label>
            <Label row="0" col="1" class="list-group-item bg-primary" text="name"></Label>
            <Label row="0" col="2" class="list-group-item bg-primary" text="supplier"></Label>
            <Label row="0" col="3" class="list-group-item bg-primary" text="Qty"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
            </template>
            <template nsTemplateKey="cell" let-stockTransaction="item">
                <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="* * * *">
                    <Label row="0" col="0" [text]="stockTransaction.Date" class="list-group-item"></Label>
                    <Label row="0" col="1" [text]="stockTransaction.TransactionType_Name" class="list-group-item"></Label>
                    <Label row="0" col="2" [text]="stockTransaction.SupplierMaster_Name" class="list-group-item"></Label>
                    <Label row="0" col="3" [text]="stockTransaction.Qty" class="list-group-item"></Label>
                </GridLayout>
            </template>

        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>

        my showStockTransactions() function:

        showStockTransactions() {
                this.stockTransactions.push('1 jan 2017', 'nametest', 'abc', '88');
                this.stockTransactions.push('1 jan 2012', 'name', 'abcd', '8');
            }

my rmHeaderModel class:

export class rmHeaderModel {
    constructor(
        item1: string,
        item2: string,
        item3: string,
        item4: string,
        type: string
    ) 
    {}

}

And then I instantiate it in the controller as follows:

ngOnInit() {        
        this.stockTransactions = [];
        this.header  = new rmHeaderModel("Date", "Name", "Supplier", "Qty", "header");
    }

my templateSelector function:

public templateSelector = (item: any, index: number, items: any) => {
        return item.type || "cell";
    }
```

Comment: Is this happening on iOS or Android!? For iOS you list-view should have some initial size, otherwise, it will not  occupy any space. Try setting height for your GridLayout (or if you are using nativescript-theme-core you can simply apply `class="list-group-item"` for the Grid)

Comment: regarding the non-repeating headers in yournlist-view.. you can now create itemTemplates for your list=views.. for example look here https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/common-screens/lists/two-lines-grouped.html

Comment: @Nick Iliev Thanks thanks thanks!!!    I was struggling with this for the past three days now and started to think it's time to give up on Angular2/Nativescript:)...  Please add your above two comments as the answer so I can accept it

Comment: @Nick Iliev It worked fine for a few minutes now for some reason it just shows the headers twice...  I updated my code...  does tht look OK to you?  this inconsistent behaviour is driving me insane...  It worked fine and I didn't change anything now when re-compiling it doesn't work anymore suddenly...

Comment: I have tried your code and it works as expected at my side. What I have don to test it is open this example https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/common-screens-category/lists-category/single-line-grouped/grouped-single-line.component.html#L5-L23 and replacing the list-view with yours  (changing the source and to use the `countries ` and the binding the use only property `name`)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [archived in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134258/discussion-on-question-by-user2094257-angular-nativescript-listview-doesnt-sho).

Comment: @Nick Iliev when you see this please add your answer so I can accept it...  Your solution worked fine at the end the only issue was that the header model wasn't in the same array as the stockTransactions which is why it didn't show...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to change `let-stockTransaction="item"` to `let-item="item"` and use it as `[text]="item.Date"`, but you may be using Angular syntax that's new to me.

And shouldn't `this.stockTransactions.push('1 jan 2017', 'nametest', 'abc', '88');` be:

```
this.stockTransactions.push({
  Date: '1 jan 2017',
  TransactionType_Name: 'nametest',
  SupplierMaster_Name: 'abc',
  Qty: '88'
});
```

Comment: I changed the push statement to stockTransactions.push(new StockTransactionModel(...));  does that look ok?  Also I got that let-stockTransaction="item" from 

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/common-screens-category/lists-category/single-line-grouped/grouped-single-line.component.html#L60-L65

(let-country="item")...  Am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: @user2094257 `let-yourVarName="item"` and then `yourVarName.property` is absolutely ok syntax for Angular-2

Comment: Cool, nice to know!