# Angular2/Nativescript: How to add an activity indicator and bind it to a variable in controller

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am busy with a Angular2/Nativescript app and struggling to display an activity indicator...  I don't see any indicator when I run the below code...  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

my xml:

```
<StackLayout *ngIf="busy">
    <ActivityIndicator busy="busy"></ActivityIndicator>
</StackLayout>
```

my typescript:

```
busy: boolean = true;
```

So am I understanding this correctly?  Is it possible to bind an activity indicator to a boolean variable in my controller?

Comment: What's the output you are expecting? :)

Comment: @AJT_82  I'm expecting an activity indicator?  Spinning loader hopefully:)  is that possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using any binding for your **busy** attribute.
Change your code so atht your property will have one-way binding

```
ActivityIndicator [busy]="busy"></ActivityIndicator>
```

Full example as follows:

app.component.html

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button text="Toggle Busy property" (tap)="toogleIndicator()"></Button>
    <ActivityIndicator #activityIndicator width="100" height="100" [busy]="busy" ></ActivityIndicator>
</StackLayout>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "ui/activity-indicator";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./setting-busy.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public activityIndicator: ActivityIndicator;
    public busy: boolean;

    @ViewChild("activityIndicator") ac: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activityIndicator = this.ac.nativeElement;
        this.busy = true;
    }

    public toogleIndicator() {
        this.activityIndicator.busy = !this.activityIndicator.busy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick Iliev that did it:)

Comment: btw here's another question you answered in the comments but you didin't add your solution as an answer, Please add your comments as an answer so I can accept it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874220/angular-nativescript-listview-doesnt-show-at-all